# 60s (or earlier) book with elevator-like time travel, a sentient planet in the future and a blockage of time by aliens from gas giants

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I read this book in the 70s and was quite an old book then maybe 60s or earlier. I have read *The End of Eternity* but there were similarities but the male female main characters were more naive.

Time travel was like an elevator and the main characters (man and his girlfriend) travel to the distant future and distant past. I remember the extreme future mankind has gone but I remember the planet was sentient.

Part of the story revolved around a blockage in a section of time, this turned out to be blocked by an alien presence from one of our gas giants. These aliens were also trying to stop humans from developing space travel. Not much to go on but I also remember that the temperature in space was a theme used to stop the development of space travel.

The story started in the near future for the book, time travel was available but space travel had been discouraged and I think this was on purpose and was related to the future blockage in time. I do remember the main characters traveled to the distant past (encountering dinosaurs) and the distant future were mankind had died out. I think they were running from something.

Comment: Is there anything else you remember about this book? Like the language, or anything from [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/70236)? Feel free to [edit] any details you come up with to you post.

Comment: Some of the details match up with _[The End of Eternity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_End_of_Eternity)_ by Asimov, but that features no aliens, just different factions of humans. The time machine does indeed look like an elevator and there is a blockage involved, by one of the factions.

Comment: Also, welcome to [scifi.se]. Have you taken the [tour] yet?

Comment: This is almost certainly The End of Eternity for all the reasons SQB mentions.  There is no sentient planet or aliens; I am guessing you are conflating some different works.

Comment: Ok, I changed my mind.  It did suggestively sound like Asimov's *The End of Eternity*, but "I remember the planet was sentient" is strangely out of place.  And he's not mixing that part in from *Nemesis* because that one is from 1989.  I don't know what to think.

Comment: Do Andrew Harlan, Laban Twissell, Noÿs Lambent, Vikkor Mallansohn and a message sent through time using the word ATOM as an initialism for "All the Talk Of the Market" in an advert with a mushroom cloud background image ring a bell? And was time specified in centuries rather than years, so the year 1945 was given as the 19.45th century?

Comment: @b_jonas Isn't it possible that he read Nemesis in 1989 or sometime in the 90's, and that now, another 25+ years later, he confuses the details?

Comment: @DuaneDibbley Nah, Nemesis is not relevant here. It's not even the planet that's sentient there. It only came to my mind because it's another of the stand-alone novels loosely connected to the Robots-Foundation universe (Foundation legends if you will).  The jury is out until either Will comes back or one of the story-id gurus identify this.

Comment: @b_jonas I see. I haven't read Nemesis. But  The end of Eternity is my all time favourite, to the point where if I were expelled from society and allowed to bring one single item, I'd bring that book. :D

Comment: I read this in the 70s and was quite an old book then maybe 60s or earlier. I have read The End of Eternity but there were similarities but the male female main characters were more naive. The story started in the near future for the book, time travel was available but space travel had been discouraged and I think this was on purpose and was related to the future blockage in time. I do remember the main characters traveled to the distant past (encountering dinosaurs) and the distant future were mankind had died out. I think they were running from something.